# React native, Redux: it is must to wrap the app.js file in the react native with the provider of the react-redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am beginner to the redux and I specifically want to know that is it important if you want to use redux in your react native application you must have to wrap your app.js file with the provider or you can do it with each component. As I know about the provider job it actually connects our states of the app with the redux library.

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each component with a `Provider` but it's usually useless (unless you have multiple stores in your app.

> Since any React component in a React Redux app can be connected, most
>   applications will render a `<Provider>` at the top level, with the
>   entire app’s component tree inside of it.

To understand why [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider) suggest to wrap the entire app with a `Provider`, the best is to understand how `Provider` works.
In fact, react-redux uses `React Context` to pass the store to all nested components: react-redux Provider is the context Provider and `connect()` function is the context Consumer.

Useful links: [React Context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) - [react-redux context usage](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#understanding-context-usage)